# I am not able to launch the browser by using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

My Code :

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class FirstAutomation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\sony\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://wwww.google.com");
      }
}
```

Exceptions

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: C:\Users\sony\Downloads\chromedriver_win32.exe
>       at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:534)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:136)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:131)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:32)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:329)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:123)
>       at FirstAutomation.main(FirstAutomation.java:8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow the below steps to add the Chromedriver.exe

> Right Click on your Selenium Project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External Class Folder

Note: kindly cross-check the chrome driver Path location in your pc and make sure the chrome driver version and google chrome version's match each other

[Link](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) to download the latest Chrome Driver

I hope the above process Works

Comment: Ok Vikas. Thanks for the quick answer. I will follow ur suggestions and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks Vikas. It worked. The browser versions were different. I was using 79 and the driver which I downloaded was 80. I had downloaded 80 assuming that I was using the latest version. U r a star. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Vikas Dadi. I had downloaded chrome driver of 80 version and the actual browser being used on the laptop was 79, hence the error. But now it is working fine after deleting the driver and reinstalling the driver of the same version.

Comment: this is not an answer.

Comment: what so u mean @CoreyGoldberg. the browser versions were different. And I downloaded the driver executable of the same version which I was using currently and gave the correct path. There were the two mistakes I was making. path wasnt correct and driver versions were different

Comment: still not an answer to what was asked